# Dynamically change background images in React from local folder

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, background

I've been trying to load  background images dynamically on my React app, but it only works when I link to my Google drive. I want to do this locally, and I've pasted the images on the immediate directory. But it still won't load on my app.
I have 21 images from 0-20 all png format in src folder

```js
var bgp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
this.setState({
  chrome: color,
  photo: bgp,
  quote: randomQuote.quote,
  author: randomQuote.name
})
render() {
    var bodyP = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${onUse}.png)`,
      transition: 'all linear 2.5s',
      height: '100vh',
      width: '100vw',
    }
    return ( <div id = "wrapper" onLoad = {this.getQuote} style = {bodyP} >
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: What's the value of onUse and did you check in the debugger what was the path to the background image url in the interpreted styles?

Comment: can u please paste how you've done your directory path?

Answer (score 0):

if it worked fine with goggle drive before then I'm pretty sure this is a problem with how you've written your directory path.
try creating an  and write your path leading to one of these pictures if the image didn't render, then keep trying to find the right way to write your path or take a look at some documentation until u see the image render, after that, u can use the right directory path in your code.
hope this works for u.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I moved the photo folder to the public folder and then used the (process.env.PUBLIC_URL) file path description to the public path as explained by https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/ and navigated to the photo folder. So my code looks like:

```js
 getPhoto() {
    var bgp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
   
   this.setState({
        photo: bgp,
    })
    
  }
  
var onUse = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/Quote-photos/"+ this.state.photo + '.png';

 var bodyP = {backgroundImage: `url(${onUse})`,
              transition: 'all linear 2.5s',
              height: '100vh',
              width: '100vw'}
```